# Displaying numeric value in label area of iPhone using stringWithFormat

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0, stringwithformat

I am new to Objective C and the iPhone SDK, and am trying to figure out the following as a simple example of displaying a numeric result in a label area:

```
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", 55];
```

This code above displays the number "55" in the label area. However, the following code results in the display of "0" (with calculationResult declared as a double variable type in the header file):

```
calculationResult = 55;
label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d", calculationResult];
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should use `%f` for a float or double.  If you don't want to print any decimal places, you should use `%.0f`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a double, use the `%f` notation, not `%d` - `%d` is for **d**ecimal numbers, while `%f` is for **f**loating point types (including doubles).